# ggplot invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am getting the below error msg when running ggplot pie chart...any idea what issue could be?

code is :

```
ggplot(pie_unrated, aes(x = "FEBRUARY IBG UNRATED Book COMPOSITION", y = prop, 
fill = ProductDetails)) + geom_bar(width = 1, 
stat = "identity", color = "white") 
+ coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) + ggpubr::fill_palette("jco") 
+theme_void()
```

My error Msg :

```
 Error in +coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) : 
    invalid argument to unary operator
```

>

```
 dput(head(pie_unrated)
structure(list(RatingStatus = c("UNRATED", "UNRATED", "UNRATED", 
"UNRATED", "UNRATED", "UNRATED"), ProductDetails = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("ACB", "Bonds", "Cash and Short Term", 
"Deposit with Banks", "LBD", "LC", "LG", "loan", "Loan", "OD", 
"Treasury Bonds"), class = "factor"), counts = c(10L, 1L, 21L, 
102L, 758L, 126L), prop = c(1, 0.1, 2.1, 10, 74.5, 12.4), lab.ybos = c(0.5, 
1.05, 2.15, 8.2, 50.45, 93.9)), .Names = c("RatingStatus", "ProductDetails", 
"counts", "prop", "lab.ybos"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "RatingStatus", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:5), group_sizes = 6L, biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    RatingStatus = "UNRATED"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame", vars = "RatingStatus", drop = TRUE, .Names = "RatingStatus"))
```

Comment: its there -- before coord_polar

Comment: you are correct, but `ggplot2` does not like `+` at the start of code line

Comment: aaaah ok -- understood. thanks so much! ggplot is a picky one

Comment: To be clear, it's an R thing not a ggplot thing. If you have `1` on a line and `+2` on the next line, you won't get 3. (However, you also  won't get an error because `+2` is valid syntax by itself, unlike `+ coord_polar()` which can't stand on its own.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(pie_unrated, 
     aes(x = "FEBRUARY IBG UNRATED Book COMPOSITION", y = prop, fill = ProductDetails)) + 
geom_bar(width = 1,stat = "identity", color = "white") + 
coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) + ggpubr::fill_palette("jco") + theme_void()
```